# The rows in a listView are not updating using Kendo MVVM

Tags: kendo-ui

I am testing out Kendo's ui MVVM capabilities and can't seem to work out how to update the viewModel items so they update rows in a listView.

It updates fine if I replace all items with the new (json) items sent to me through a websocket but I am trying to simply update the matching items and expect to see these changes appear in my view (the listView div).

This is an extract of my code - what am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="listView">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>BatchID</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Progress</th>
                <th>Owner</th>
                <th>(Est)Completion Time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-template="row-template" data-bind="source: items"></tbody>
        <tfoot data-template="footer-template" data-bind="source: this"></tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

then in my script blocks:

```
<script id="row-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: BatchID"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Status"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Progress"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Owner"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: EstCompletion"></td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script id="footer-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Batch count: #: total() #
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var viewModel = kendo.observable({
            items: [],
            total: function () {
                return this.get("items").length;
            }
        });

        kendo.bind($("#listView"), viewModel);


        // register this reporting widget
        var webSocket = CreateSocket("screen2", "reporting", "default", true);

        webSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
            try {

                var smd = JSON.parse(e.data);
                var data = JSON.parse(smd.Data);

                jQuery.each(data, function () {

                    var id = this.BatchID;
                    var newItem = this;

                    var hasRow = false;
                    jQuery.each(viewModel.items, function () {
                        var itemTemp = this;
                        if (itemTemp.BatchID == id) {
                            hasRow = true;
                            itemTemp.Status == newItem.Status;
                            itemTemp.Progress = newItem.Progress;
                            itemTemp.EstCompletion = newItem.EstCompletion;
                            itemTemp.Completed = newItem.Completed;
                        }
                    });

                    if (!hasRow) {
                        var reportItem = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
                            BatchID: "",
                            Owner: "",
                            Status: "",
                            Progress: "",
                            EstCompletion: "",
                            Completed: ""
                        });

                        reportItem.BatchID = this.BatchID;
                        reportItem.Owner = this.Owner;
                        reportItem.Status = this.Status;
                        reportItem.Progress = this.Progress;
                        reportItem.EstCompletion = this.EstCompletion;
                        reportItem.Completed = this.Completed;

                        viewModel.items.push(reportItem);
                    }

                });

            }
            catch (e) {
                //alert(e.message);
            }
        };

        webSocket.onopen = function (e) {

            // now register our interest in receiving reporting monitoring data
            var bor = new SymMsgUp(GlobalInfo.UserID, "reporting", "default", "dfregister");

            // convert to Json and send it off the the server
            webSocket.send(bor.toServer());
        };

        webSocket.onclose = function (e) {
            //responseDiv.innerHTML += '<div>Disconnected.</div>';
        };

        webSocket.onerror = function (e) {
            //responseDiv.innerHTML += '<div>Error</div>'
        };



    });

</script>
```

The updates take place ( I checked with a debugger ) - but these changes are NOT reflected in the view..

Also, I created the var reportItem = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({ etc etc for testing - I rather not have to do this and simply dump the array of json objects into my observable collection (viewMode.Items).  This works nicely but again it doesn't update when I update individual items...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just received an answer from Kendo (after almost a week because I am using a trial license...) on how this can be done:

```
$(function(){
  var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    products: [
        { name: "Hampton Sofa", price: 989.99, unitsInStock: 39 },
        { name: "Perry Sofa", price: 559.99, unitsInStock: 17 },
        { name: "Donovan Sofa", price: 719.99, unitsInStock: 29 },
        { name: "Markus Sofa", price: 839.99, unitsInStock: 3 }
    ],
    newPrice: 0,
    itemIndex: 0,
    setPrice: function(e){
      this.products[this.itemIndex].set("price", this.newPrice);
    }
});

kendo.bind($("body"), viewModel);

});
```

EDIT:
Just to explain that the line that does the trick is:

```
this.products[this.itemIndex].set("price", this.newPrice);
```

This is what I was after - a way of updating an entry in their observable collection that DOES update the ui.

Comment: What does this have to do with your question? Am I missing something or did you update the wrong question?

Comment: @OnaBai - the originial question was about updating items from a collection that are bound to a Kendo list using Kendo's MVVM binding.  When I update an item in this collection it wasn't updating the entry in the list (the ui) - you suggested replacing (splice) the item which works well but Kendo have just shown how this is done through this set 'property' statement which negates the need of a splice.

Comment: I cannot see in their solution all the complexity about web sockets and just see that the solution introduces a computed field. Was the text of the question to KendoUI technical support the same? Different questions, different answers.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - sometimes it is difficult to extract the exact question out of experimental code.  Looking at your answer it looks like you were answering the correct question though.  The question I asked Kendo was actually a reference to this stackoverflow aricle!  I do thank you for your efforts though!

Comment: my concerns are about other people reading your question, then KendoUI forum answer (accepted answer) and not understanding how one connects to the other. You might always edit your original question in order to make it fit better with the answer.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that using the item.set('key', value) method works for altering dataSource objects for kendoMobileListView

Comment: Marcel's edit to the answer is gold. I wouldn't have guessed this one. **Using .set() on a single item in the array makes observable pick up that the array changed.**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's a feature or a bug but what you are trying to do is not supported. If you update one element of your list then it is actually updated **BUT** if you update a field of one item of the list then it is not.

This means that only first level is actually *observed*.

So, what you should do is actually replace current element with the received one. Instead of:

```
if (itemTemp.BatchID == id) {
    hasRow = true;
    itemTemp.Status == newItem.Status;
    itemTemp.Progress = newItem.Progress;
    itemTemp.EstCompletion = newItem.EstCompletion;
    itemTemp.Completed = newItem.Completed;
}
```

you should:

```
jQuery.each(viewModel.items, function () {
    var itemTemp = this;
    if (itemTemp.BatchID == id) {
        hasRow = true;
        itemTemp.Status == newItem.Status;
        itemTemp.Progress = newItem.Progress;
        itemTemp.EstCompletion = newItem.EstCompletion;
        itemTemp.Completed = newItem.Completed;
    }
});
```

You should:

```
jQuery.each(viewModel.items, function (idx, old) {
    if (old.BatchID == id) {
        hasRow = true;
        viewModel.items.splice(idx, 1, newItem);
    }
});
```

**BTW:** did you realize that you had `itemTemp.Status == newItem.Status;` instead of `itemTemp.Status = newItem.Status;`

So, your code after some *cleaning* should read like:

```
webSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
    try {

        var smd = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var data = JSON.parse(smd.Data);

        jQuery.each(data, function () {
            var newItem = this;
            var hasRow = false;
            jQuery.each(viewModel.items, function (idx, oldItem) {
                if (oldItem.BatchID == newItem.BatchID) {
                    hasRow = true;
                    viewModel.items.splice(idx, 1, newItem);
                }
            });
            if (!hasRow) {
                viewModel.items.push(newItem);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        //alert(e.message);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that Ona - that did the trick - shame it doesn't support multi level observations like wpf does but maybe in future?...   Sorry for the messy code, it got more and more bloated to find a way round the Kendo issue! - bug was well spotted though! :)

Comment: Now the item is actually replaced I have a new problem with the (selectable: true) feature of the kendoListView using a template.  When the item is selected but subsequently replaced it loses its 'selected' status.  Do I have to work around this myself by toggling a 'selected class' and adding it again after it is reinserted?

Comment: @Marcel event that the question said _listview_ in your example you were actually not using a `kendoListView`, maybe the code that you showed was a modified version, so it's not that easy for me to show you exact code to this other question. Basically, you should start getting which is the selected node in the `listView`. You do this invoking `select()`. Then, if you find that are replacing the selected node, you should select the replaced version by using `select()` again but this time with an argument that is the node. If you want, post a question with the new code and I take a look into it.